# Slide of UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ipad, sdk

I made a slideview using a uiview and detecting touches to move pages. This slideview is almost like [this](http://lievendekeyser.net/index.php?module=messagebox&action=message&msg_id=1351), except that I made it works like a UITableView.

Now I'm using this to uivews with uiscrollviews. The problem is, "how to distribute touch events to scrollview or slideview?". I had the logic to do. Basically, the uiscrollviews are vertical and slideview is horizontal.

I tried hitTest to keep the touchBegan,Moved,Ended in slideview. When I get a touch movement horizontally, I keep to slideview, when vertically, distribute to uiscrollview. But I cannot figure out how to distribute events to uiscrollview.

Calling *[scrollView touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]* doesn't work. I supposed uiscrollview has a different way to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If you don't find a clue to your answer, probably, you're wrong.*

UIScrollView uses a own way to get touchesBegan, Moved and Ended. Way that I don't, but it's mean if you override touchesBegan to make UIScrollView stops to work, you won't get it. Using hitTest in superview of scroll, you can get the touches before UIScrollView but you can't change the touches target while touches is happening.

After all, there is one way to solve this, ashly, three ways.

**1- Simulate touches**
I didn't test this, you'll know below. Events come from UIWindow and distributed to subview by *- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event*. We don't know how touches target is saved, and change this is completely out of question. But we can use the idea of override superview's hitTest to know what the user will do to make a 'WA' to change the target. To do this, simulate a event of touch ended. Supposed target will be reset. Simulate a event of touch begin again, and this time make sure to let hittest get scrollview.
You can find how simulate events [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone.html). The problem is, probably your app will be rejected due using private methods.

**2- Make your own UIScrollView**
This should be the best or the worst, depending what you want to do. I believe it's painful. And isn't what you want to do right now.

**3- Surrender to 'Nest UIScrollView'**
To make slideshow of pdf, hq, docs and books, it's the best and painless way. Put a UIScrollView inside another and let them reach an agreement of scrolling. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/NestedScrollViews/NestedScrollViews.html